# Continuity and integrability of a function $f:[0,1] \to l_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

Good morning
I’m working with this problem at the moment:
Let’s say that we have a function $f:[0,1] \to l_2$ where base is $(e_i)=(0,0,0,….,0,1,0,…,0,0)$ and then $f(q_i)=e_i$ and $f(r)=Q$
we have to show that this function isn’t continuous but is integrable.

Continuous:
This is clear $|f(q_i)-f(r)|=1$ but $|r-q_1|=0 $

Integrable:
I know that we should show that using sum of a sequence of divisions but I’m not sure how to write it properly.

Comment: Can you clarify what $l_2$ is? I'm not familiar

Comment: l_2 is a space of sequence squares of absolutely sumable

Comment: What is $q_i$?  Some enumeration of the rationals?      What do you mean by $f(r)=Q$?

Comment: We can say more: let q_n be a sequence of numbers that belongs to rational numbers so: $q_1=0,r_1$,$q_2=0,r_1r_2$ And so on this sequence is convergent to $q_n=0,r_1r_2…r_n$

Comment: q are rational numbers but r are not rational numbers. $f(q_i)=e_i$ means that if $e_i=(0,0,0…,0,1,0,…0,0,0)$ where 1 is on i-place